# Likelihood ratio test for structural change (time series) in R

Tags: r, time-series

Is there a package that includes a likelihood ratio test for time series data with an unknown number of breaks in R? My search wasn't very successful, yet...

Comment: Did you find the [strucchange package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/) in your search?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way. Check this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324960/qlr-test-for-coefficient-stability-in-var-model-with-r)

This is called "QLR-Testing"

You loop through your series and F-Test dummy breaks at a certain interval. The exact values for this are given in many books concerning econometrics, such as Stock/Watson. Note that your critical values differs from the Chow test and also depends on the range of values you discard at the beginning and the end.

The Fstats does pretty much what you want, here is the manual [clicky](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/strucchange.pdf)
´

You can also easily write the function yourself using a loop and regular F/Chow-Tests, this might give you more control and is a good exercise.

Either way, you are going to need a list of critical values.

Comment: Hello IMA. I would appreciate if you have any advice about my question here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59326/breakpoint-for-bivariate-data