# Breakpoint for bivariate data

Tags: regression, change-point, multivariate-regression, structural-change

The breakpoint(s) estimation approach implemented in the [strucchange package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/vignettes/strucchange-intro.pdf) (Zeilei & al) seems to work very well (based on my little experience with this package on real case studies).

Is there an existing similar approach for multivariate regression models ? Otherwise, would it be easy to generalize the strucchange method ? (Unfortunately I do not have time to study this question myself).

### Update

Here is an animated example (thanks to [Yihui Xie's animation package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html)). I have a bivariate dataset, each pair $(x,y)$ has been recorded at some date:

```
         x        y       date
1 3.690131 6.797999 25/01/2012
2 3.552278 7.055363 07/02/2012
3 3.623821 6.745984 10/02/2012
4 3.600735 6.847450 10/02/2012
5 3.726609 6.894321 14/02/2012
6 3.578204 6.823344 17/02/2012
...
```

Sarting $n_1=40$, I estimate the shape of the isodensity ellipses of the first $n_1$ observations as well as the shape of the isodensity ellipses of the remaining $n_2=n-n_1$ observations. These are simulated data. For some $n_0>40$ I have simulated Gaussian bivariate i.i.d pairs $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1, \ldots, n_0$, and then I have simulated Gaussian bivariate i.i.d pairs $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=n_0+1, \ldots, n$ with different parameters. The question is: find $n_0$, which is here a breakpoint for the model `lm(cbind(x,y)~1)` in R syntax.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean multiple linear regression (or GLMs) with more than one independent variable?

Comment: @COOLSerdash No, I mean regression models for a multivariate dependent variable. Like `lm(cbind(x,y)~time` in R.

Answer (score 2):

Stephane, I answer this thread because you linked it in another post.
Sadly I have not come across calculations for a QLR test with a set of dependent variables instead of one. Seeing as it (at least it used to be) considerable hard to calculate a good table of critical values for the QLR test, I don't know if such a thing exists.

Now you say that your variables are i.i.d. If they are jointly normal but independent, you can go ahead and do a split regression on both regressands and QLR test this. I don't know if you'd theoretically needed different critical values for this as well, but I suggest you err on the side of caution when it comes to significance. Other than that this should at least give a good indication where the structural break might be.

If the variables are not independent I'd probably also do this, and maybe build a normal multiple regression model out of the thing, for example x=y+t or x-y=t or something and run a few simulations on how this tests QLR wise, but this is of course trial and error if you don't want to create a whole new table on your own.

I am sorry I couldn't be of further help, I am not versed enough to give you a definite solution on the problem as I doubt one would get around having to calculate the fitting statistic yourself. 
Hope this gives you some ideas.

When if comes to implementing the QLR test, just loop F-Tests over the model with break at t/vs. model without, while cutting off ~20% of the dataset at both sides (depends on the table of critical values you use, it will be stated in the table). Display the F-Values and pick the one which seems most likely, pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hello IMA. Thank you. There's no set of dependent variables. Data are independent pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ from a bivariate Gaussian (the pair $(x_i,y_i)$ is independent of the pair $(x_j,y_j)$, but $x_i$ is not independent of $y_i$). In my example above, there's no dependent variable. I didn't have the time to study the method for the univariate case, but if it is likelihood-based it should be straightforward to generalize it to the multivariate case.

Comment: Oooppss sorry... I always confound "dependent" and "independent" variables (I don't like these words). So you're right, there are two dependent variables.

Comment: It's shit terminology I know, sorry. Just read it as "regressands". In any case if you are up to it, this is the article you can work through: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2951764?uid=3737864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102259593731 -- I know that there are some updated tables with better values out there now, so maybe check newer research.

Comment: They are, actually, right here: http://www.pipedreamer.org/~tim/Thesis/2013-03/thesis/andrews2003.pdf -- the Andrews article should guide you towards the papers you'll need to generalize this for your case of a bivariate regressand.